# Can I use a hotshoe sync adapter with the Canon multifunction hotshoe?

Tags: off-camera-flash, compatibility, hotshoe

A long time ago I used a Canon 400D together with Nikon Speedlights SB-25 and SB-24.
To trigger them, I used this device in the screenshot to connect via cable.

Many years later (today) I tried this again with my Canon EOS R10, but neither flash is triggering. I turned of Silent Shutter Function and also tried Shuttermodes "Mechanical" and "Elec. 1st-curtain". No Success. Anyone having an idea?

Also if this won't work, is there possibility to use my old flashes with the Canon EOS R10?

Thanks in advance for any help.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would check that your adapter seats properly in the new multifunction hotshoe so that the sync pin on the bottom is actually touching the sync contact (the big one in the center of the "square". The new physical shape of the multifunction hotshoe with additional electronic contacts in the back may not be compatible with the adapter you have.

As far as I know, the new multi-function hotshoe on the R10 *should* be compatible with any flash gear that worked on the older traditional Canon hotshoe of your 400D, but this is still new territory as the multi-function hotshoe only came out in 2021 on the R3, and folks only really got their hands on multifunction hotshoes starting in 2022 and 2023 bodies (R7, R10, R8, R6ii).

I would also check that you know the following things are good and work:

- Flash (test button)
- Batteries in flash (test cycle on a smart charger)
- Cable (swap cables)
- Adapter (try on another camera; or possibly tape over the small four non-sync contacts on the hotshoe and mount the flash directly on the hotshoe.
- That the R10's flash setting isn't turned off.
- That the R10's pop-up flash is not engaged and the hotshoe's [microswitch](https://shimworld.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/canon-hotshoe-fix/) is not broken or stuck.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thank you so much for your input.
I bought a wireless yonguo trigger together with some simple yongnuo flashes and it works. So I don't know, what the real problem was...

Comment: @RafaelWörner I'd hazard an issue with the hotshoe adapter or cable. Also, just me, but I'd recommend a Godox TT600/XPro-C setup over a Yongnuo YN-560IV/YN-560-TX setup: more easily expandable in the future, and you'd get HSS and costs about the same.  But I drank the Godox kool-aid ages ago.

Comment: Actually did so shortly after because also of the availability of the stuio flashes. Thanks for the advice.